# Google Spreadsheets script to automatically color an entire row based on a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm taking over a group membership list, which has been passed down through a few 'generations' of leadership, and I can't *quite* figure it out...

The spreadsheet *used* to automatically update the color of each row (from 6 different options), based on the value of the cell in column 10 - but has mysteriously stopped doing so.

I've been looking at the script in there, but I can't quite figure it out - does anyone have any advice? Would be greatly appreciated!

```
function colorRow(r){

  // only uncomment for Debuging
  //r = 2;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());

  // will get the row
  var row = dataRange.getValues()[0];

  // change the row[8] to row[?] where ? is your column number
  var cellValue = row[10];

  if(cellValue == "1"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 0, 255);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "2"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 153, 0);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "3"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(153, 204, 255);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "4"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(0, 255, 0);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "5"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(0, 255, 255);
  }
  else if(cellValue == "6"){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 0);
  }

  // not sure if I need to flush...
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
}

function onEdit(event)
{
  colorRow(event.source.getActiveRange().getRowIndex());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say the color depends on content of column 10 but the code shows   `var cellValue = row[10];`

Arrays are 0 indexed, that means you are getting content of column 11...(columns in spreadsheets are indexed to 1)

Wouldn't that be the issue ?

**EDIT :** while you are looking at your script, I would also suggest to use a different condition in your `IF` statements because the one you use is very fragile : if someone types a space before or after the number it will fail...
What I 'd do is something like this :

```
  if(cellValue.toString().match("1") == "1"){
```

it will 'catch' the '1' value even if it's not alone in its cell and will work up to a value of 9 (after that you'll get a confusion with 10, 11 etc...)
(but this is only a suggestion...;)

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, Serge - I agree it's safer to have a condition that will catch numbers even with a space.

For whatever reason, it works with the column set as it is now. The main issue remaining is that r: if I un-comment r=2 and substitute for the row I want to recolor (ie: r=323), it works for that single row, but I can't figure out how to make it work for all rows, and and future rows. Anyway, thanks very much for your help!